# Using partials on arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I'm confused by how partials behave with respect to arrays.

### Simple Example

I have the following in a view:

```
render :partial => "foobars", :object => [1, 2, 3]
```

And in _foobars.html.erb, I have

```
<%= foobars.size %>
<%= foobars[0] %>
```

The weird thing is that what gets displayed is "444" and "101", not "3" and "1".
Is something special happening because I'm passing in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
render :partial => "foobars", :locals => {:object => [1, 2, 3]}
```

and inside the partial

```
<%= object.size %>
<%= object[0] %>
```

Comment: Hmm, that works. But I thought :object automatically referred to an instance variable in my partial with the same name as the partial? (e.g., that :object referred to the 'foobars' variable, in this case)

Comment: no, I don't think so, I think what you pass to locals should be a symbol of the expected object in the partial, as indicated here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Partials

Comment: Oh, according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html the behavior I was thinking of has been removed in Rails 3 (and was deprecated in 2.3). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What Jed says works but what you are looking for is really

```
render :partial => "foobars", :collection => [1,2,3]
```

Inside the partial, the iteration will happen by itself on the passed array and `foobars` will hold the array element of each iteration

```
<%= foobars %>
```

will give 1, 2 and 3 inside the partial.

Comment: No you can't. This will iterate through each object in that collection, assigning it to the local variable `foobars` inside the partial. There is no `size` method on a `Fixnum`, nor a `[]` method.